# Looking for the name of a scifi/horror anthology with B&W illustrations

Tags: story-identification, horror

1. It had black and white illustrations
2. There was a story about a God Program that gets corrupted by a virus and turns into an Antichrist Program
3. A woman who keep growing from baby to adult again and again and dies being tied to a radiator
4. A story about raining silver combs

Answer (score 9):

I suspect this may be [The Anthology of Fantasy & the Supernatural](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/The_anthology_of_fantasy_the_supernatura.html?id=2RDF0cw8Q9MC&redir_esc=y) by Stephen Jones and David Sutton. [The ISFDB entry is here](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?35234).

I have to confess this is based on flimsy evidence. I spotted the anthology while Googling for something else. I don't own it and I cannot find a copy of it anywhere. However if I use Google Books to search for the rain of silver combs I find:

> Her mother ran to the front window. Annie could see past her through the window and into the front yard. Where thousands of combs fell in a shimmering, silver toothed deluge.

This is from the Steve Rasnic Tem story [Angel Combs](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40560) - I have a copy in his anthology City Fishing.

If I search for *radiator* I find:

> With a set of handcuffs sometimes used as a prop, I cuffed her to the radiator in the bedroom and made sure she was comfortable. She didn't fight it; maybe she figured it was time. I wasn't actually killing her, only allowing her to die. I guessed about six more hours would do it.

I think this is the story [Daddy](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?710101) by Earl Goodwin - I have a copy in Shadows 7 edited by Charles L. Grant.

Finally, searching for *virus* does find some matches but the snippets of text shown are too ambiguous to decide if they match your memory of a virus corrupting a God program.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Rennie. Your Sleuthing identified a book I have been searching for, for the last 10 years. I will buy it!